# OLS estimator. Should it be left in terms of Y?

Tags: least-squares

I have the following model:
$Y_i = B_0 + B_1X_{1i} + B_2X_{2i} + u_i$.

I want to compute the OLS estimator using $(X'X)^{-1}(X'Y)$

I'm free to choose values for X but Y cannot have concrete values?

Should I be leaving my OLS estimator in terms of Y?
What would be your recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave it in terms of Y then the formula will look much like the above, except with numbers specified for $B_p$. This is the usual way to write a regression equation.

If you want to compute the predicted Y for specific X's, then you can do that as well.

Comment: My answer currently looks like this B^=> I cannot write the matrix so i'll give you my final answer, b0= (y2+y3)/2 ; b1= {(y4+y5)-(y2+y3)}/2 and b3=(2y1-y2-y3-2y4-2y5)/4. What should my next step be to get the predicted y? Please give me some link or some formula if possible. Thanks again for the insight...

Comment: Huh? The predicted y is given by the original formula in your question. The b are estimated by running the regression (e.g. OLS regression) based on your data. You don't calculate b in terms of y; and y shouldn't have subscripts.